# safely URL-encode hrefs (without knowing if already encoded!)

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, urlencode

I noticed that Chrome and Firefox store `document.location.href` URL-encoded while IE9 stores it unencoded.

For example:

- Chrome/FF: `http://domain.tld/some%20folder/`
- IE: `http://domain.tld/some folder/`

Is there any convention? And more important, is there a reliable way to check if it is URL-encoded without checking for vendor?

My current solution is:

```
    // helpers
var reUriToPathname = /^.*:\/\/[^\/]*|[^\/]*$/g,
    uriToPathname = function (uri) {

        return uri.replace(reUriToPathname, '');
    },
    forceEncoding = function (href) {

        // collection of manual fixes..
        return href
                .replace(/\/+/g, '/')
                .replace(/ /g, '%20')
                .replace(/'/g, '%27')
                .replace(/\[/g, '%5B')
                .replace(/\]/g, '%5D')
                .replace(/\(/g, '%28')
                .replace(/\)/g, '%29')
                .replace(/\+/g, '%2B')
                .replace(/\=/g, '%3D');
    },

    // check once with a testpath
    hrefsAreDecoded = (function () {

        var testpathname = '/a b',
            a = doc.createElement('a');

        a.href = testpathname;
        return uriToPathname(a.href) === testpathname;
    }()),

    // safely return encoded href
    getEncodedHref = function (href) {

        var a = doc.createElement('a'),
            location;

        a.href = href;
        location = uriToPathname(a.href);

        if (hrefsAreDecoded) {
            location = encodeURIComponent(location).replace(/%2F/ig, '/');
        }

        return forceEncoding(location);
    };
```

Using `getEncodedHref(document.location.href)` seems to be safe enough but can't be the best solution out there.. Any suggestions how to handle this more elegant?

Comment: TheZ Comment is equal to my answer.

Comment: There are already inbuilt JavaScript functions for encoding and decoding URLs, why are you trying to do it yourself?

Comment: @TheZ decodeURI will break paths like e.g. "/folder/100% free.txt"

Comment: @JakeRow123 you need to know whether a URL is encoded to safely decode it, see previous comment..

Comment: @lrsjng Darn, I thought it might, but I wasn't sure. encode was more obviously breakable.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
encodeURIComponent("http://asdf.com?foo=bar&bla=asdfäöü");
"http%3A%2F%2Fasdf.com%3Ffoo%3Dbar%26bla%3Dasdf%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC"

encodeURI("http://asdf.com?foo=bar&bla=asdfäöü");
"http://asdf.com?foo=bar&bla=asdf%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%BC"
```

Comment: `encodeURI("http://asdf.com?foo=bar&bla=asdfäöü");` works fine, but if it already is encoded you get encodeURI returns: `"http://asdf.com?foo=bar&bla=asdf%25C3%25A4%25C3%25B6%25C3%25BC"`

Comment: Encoding anything is pretty much broken once you've already built a query string.  The whole point is to hide special chars from whatever might try to parse them...and once you have a query string, some of those chars *correctly* are special while others *incorrectly* are special.  Thing is, at this point, they're all special.  In order to prevent that, you need to encode stuff before you add it into the URL and avoid encoding the entire URL.

Comment: @cHao actually the question is not about query strings but the pathname. If I don't know if `document.location.href` is encoded, it's not safe to simply run decode on it.. if it already is decoded for example `http://domain.tld/folder/100% free.txt` will cause problems

Comment: @lrsjng: You can't 100% know if a particular URL is encoded or not.  You can make a less-than-reliable guess via `(/\%[0-9a-f]{2}/i).test(...)`, which looks for URL-escape-like patterns, but it's perfectly legitimate for something to contain `%3F` etc even *before* encoding (or after/absent decoding).  So the only way to truly know is to convert it yourself.